# repeator having fixed header with scrolling option

Tags: asp.net, header, repeater

In asp.net , i need to put repeator with scrolling having fixed header .here do i need to use seperate css or wat. or i need to fix repeator to auto in div.or provide me any links which explains this part???? help me

repeator is in div tag

```
<div style="overflow: auto; height: 200px;">
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repSearch" runat="server">
                                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                                <table style="border: 1px solid #465c71;" cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                                                    <tr style="background-color: #465c71; color: White" align="center">
                                                        <td width="20%" align="center">
                                                            Firstname
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="20%" align="center">
                                                            Lastname
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="40%" align="center">
                                                            Emailid
                                                        </td>
                                                        <td width="35%" align="center">
                                                            Mobileno
                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </table>
                                            </HeaderTemplate>
 </div>
```

should i write any css class seperately for header and display only columns in repeator

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net panel control to achieve vertical or horizontal scrolling.

Just remove the header template and above panel make a header row of your own.

```
<table> 
<tr>
<td>
 <table style="border: 1px solid #465c71;"     cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                                                <tr style="background-color: #465c71; color: White" align="center">
                                                    <td width="20%" align="center">
                                                        Firstname
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="20%" align="center">
                                                        Lastname
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="40%" align="center">
                                                        Emailid
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td width="35%" align="center">
                                                        Mobileno
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
<asp:Panel runat="server" Id="scrollPanel" Height="200px;" Scrollbar="Vertical">
<asp:Repeater ID="id_repSearch" runat="server">
<itemteplate>
<table style="border: 1px solid #465c71;"     cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                                                <tr style="background-color: #465c71; color: White" align="center">
put your repeating controls here
</tr>
</table>
/itemtemplate>
</asp:Panel>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```